# Retrieving an object which unknown name stored in a variable as a string value

Tags: javascript

Ok, it's sort of chat application, where every contact dynamically retrieved from a server within an object has unique generated id.

```
contactlist = {0: {name:"John", id:"123"}, 1: {name:"Sarah", id:"345"}};
```

Then we create several div's with corresponding ids like id="contact123".

```
<div class="contact" id="contact123">John</div> <div class="contact" id="contact345">Sarah</div>;
```

And when you click one of them we need to call the object that contains messages with that person. (which stored in a variable with slightly different name, e.g. "conversationID123 = {...messages here...}")

```js
let contacts = document.querySelectorAll(".contact");

for (let i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
  contacts[i].addEventListener("click", ShowConversation)
}

function ShowConversation(event){
  let contactID = event.target.id;
  let conversationID = "conversationID" + contactID.slice(9);
  console.log(conversationID); // logs conversationID123 or conversationID345 not an object with messages
}




let conversationID123 = {
  me : "Hi!",
  John : "Whats up"
}

let conversationID345 = {
  me : "Are you okay?",
  Sarah : "Call me"
}
```

```html
<div class="contact" id="contact123">John</div>
<div class="contact" id="contact345">Sarah</div>

<div class="conversation-window">
<!--Messages will appear here-->
</div>
```

How to console.log that object with messages in it, knowing only it's name as a string?

Please note: 1. eval() is not preferred as it has security issues, 2. window[conversationID] or this[conversationID] also wouldn't work as they need variable to be declared at the start, but we don't know their name before we retrieve them from the server and generate new ids for them, 3. Storing variable names in a new object's key as string also wouldn't work for us, because we need to store all messages again in that new object value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing all the conversations inside another object, instead of:

```
let conversationID123 = {
  me : "Hi!",
  John : "Whats up"
}

let conversationID345 = {
  me : "Are you okay?",
  Sarah : "Call me"
}
```

do something like:

```
let allConversations = {
        conversationID123: {
          me : "Hi!",
          John : "Whats up"
        },
        conversationID345: {
          me : "Are you okay?",
          Sarah : "Call me"
        }
};
```

Then you can access the messages by keys like:

```
console.log(allConversations[conversationID]);
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you! But is there any other options?

Comment: You can also store all conversations in an array: `[{me : "Hi!", John : "Whats up"},{me : "Are you okay?", Sarah : "Call me"}]`, and then access each conversation by index, e.g. index 0 corresponds to 'John', index 1 corresponds to 'Sarah' so on as indicated by your `contactList`.